# Making non-local changes with Perl keyword API

Tags: perl

I am experimenting with writing a new keyword, via the `PL_keyword_plugin` mechanism.  The action of the keyword, however, won't be a simple code substitution at the point where the keyword is encountered in the source code.  I also need it to perform some cleanup action at the *end of the enclosing block in which the keyword occurs*.  In effect, I want to transform something like

```
{
    ...
    my_keyword;
    ...
}
```

into

```
{
    ...
    do_something();
    ...
    cleanup_something();
}
```

My two questions are:

a) Is this possible?

b) Is this possible without opening up a humongous can of worms, like having to traverse the opcode tree to seek out the boundaries of the enclosing block as it is being parsed?

Comment: Have you looked at something like [`Scope::OnExit`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Scope::OnExit)? This seems to implement precisely such cleanup functions. The XS code is surprisingly simple.

Comment: 1. For the cleanup part, use `SAVEDESTRUCTOR_X`. See Scope::OnExit for an example. /// 2. If you still need something like the keyword plugin, you should use Devel::CallParser instead. The keyword plugin is rather broken. See Syntax::Feature::QwComments and/or Syntax::Feature::Loop for an example. (They also use Lexical::Sub, which is currently broken for threaded builds of perl, but that's not a requirement for Devel::CallParser. You could simply export a symbol like a normal instead of creating one that lexically scoped.)

Comment: `Scope::OnExit` looks useful, and if nothing else, I can learn from studying the source.  Thanks.

Comment: @ikegami : `Devel::CallParser` might be just a bit over my head at this point.  I'd like to study and learn it, though.  Thanks.  It is frustrating that a feature that was added some seven years ago is still marked experimental, and is apparently at least somewhat broken.  :-/

Comment: I don't know anything about Devel::CallParser being broken, and Devel::CallParser is actually easy to use. For example, just look at [`parse_loop`](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/IKEGAMI/Syntax-Feature-Loop-v1.8.0/lib/Syntax/Feature/Loop.xs). It creates `loop BLOCK` (equivalent to `while (1) BLOCK`). The only complicated part is the opcode-tree building, which you'd need to do no matter what method you use. `PL_keyword_plugin`, on the other hand, is nigh-impossible if not impossible to do right.